# multiple info windows on a map with google maps API

Tags: infowindow

As i just begin to understand how API v3 work, i have a problem to set different content for my info windows. I'm not a programmer also!! I'd like to put several markers (no problem) with different contents. The problem is i have only one info window working, not the second one. How to attribute a content to a specific marker. Can't find the way in the google maps documentation.
Here the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.648288,8.173828),
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

var contentString = '<iframe src="http://www.360-        -----    vision.fr/panos/communes_ot_patrimoine/Sanary/" height="300px" width="500px"></iframe>'+
'<div id="content">'+
'<div id="siteNotice">'+
'</div>'+
'<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Eglise Sanary</h2>'+
'</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString
});
var image = 'images/marqueur-360.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.115145,5.789623),
map: map,
icon: image,
title:"Eglise de Sanary"
});

var contentString1 = '<iframe src="http://www.360-   vision.fr/panos/communes_ot_patrimoine/castelsardo/" height="300px" width="500px">    </iframe>'+
'<div id="content">'+
'<div id="siteNotice">'+
'</div>'+
'<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Castelsardo</h2>'+
'</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString1
});
var image = 'images/marqueur-360.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.042074,8.739624),
map: map,
icon: image,
title:"Castelsardo"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
 infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Here the link to see my map.
[map example](http://www.360-vision.fr/solutions.html)
Thanks a lot for any suggestion.
Steph. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Each infowindow can be linked to specific marker, name marker and infowindow accordingly .
Eg:

```
var marker= ....
var infowindow=...
infowindow.open(map,marker);
var marker2= ....
var infowindow2=...
infowindow2.open(map,marker2);
```